# How can I prove that the random variable $\frac{\lfloor 2^n X\rfloor}{2^n}$ is uniformly distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, uniform-distribution

> Let $X\sim Uni[0,1]$. Then define $X_n= \frac{\lfloor 2^n X\rfloor}{2^n}$. I want to show that this is uniformly distributed on $A=\{\frac{k}{2^n}: 0\leq k<2^n\}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

My Idea was the following. Let me remark that $$\frac{2^nX-1}{2^n}< \frac{\lfloor 2^n X\rfloor}{2^n}\leq \frac{2^nX}{2^n}$$then as $n\rightarrow \infty$ we get $$\frac{\lfloor 2^n X\rfloor}{2^n}\rightarrow X$$ Then for all $x\in A$ we have that $F_{X_n}(x)=\Bbb{P}\left( \frac{\lfloor 2^n X\rfloor}{2^n}\leq x\right)\rightarrow \Bbb{P}(X\leq x)$ using Fubini/Tonelli. So by portmanteau theorem we get $X_n\rightarrow X$ in distribution and hence $X_n$ has the uniform distribution.

Is this true or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why does $X_n\to X$ in distribution imply that (for some fixed $n$), $X_n$ has a uniform distribution?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen wouldn't this imply that $X_n$ has the same distribution as $X$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen but now thinking about it it does not make much sense your right. How could I fix it?

Comment: No, in fact it tells you absolutely nothing about the distribution of any given $X_n$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen ah okey but can I use my proof up to the point that $\frac{\lfloor 2^n X\rfloor}{2^n}\rightarrow X$, i.e. does this helps me to prove the statement?

Comment: I would suggest a more direct and less theoretical approach. What are the possible values $X_n$ will take as a function of $X$? And then once you know that you can tell what range of $X$ corresponds to each value and hence the probability of each value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140389/discussion-between-cristallo-and-spaceisdarkgreen).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen would it be possible to discuss this shortly in chat?

Comment: Unfortunately I’m pressed for time right now. Just think about what that expression does as a function of $X$ (and you’re not wrong that $X_n$ converges in distribution to a uniform).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen sorry I'm now a bit confused, why would it help to know that $X_n$ converges in distribution to a uniform? And which expression you mean?

Comment: I meant the defining expression for $X_n$. And it doesn’t help, as we discussed previously… I was just saying you weren’t wrong about that fact.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen ah perfect thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems much harder than it needs to be though.

Let us define $$X_n = 2^n \times \frac{\lfloor 2^n X \rfloor}{2^n}.$$
Then $X_n$ is clearly integral; the numerator $2^n \times \lfloor X \rfloor$ is both integral and is clearly an integral multiple of the denominator $2^n$. Furthermore, $X_n$ must be nonnegative [lest $X$ is negative], and it must be less than $2^n$ with probability $1$ [lest $X \ge 1$, note that as $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, that $X=1$ with probability $0$, and $X$ cannot be larger than $1$.] So the support of $X_n$ is $A_n =\{0,1,2,\ldots, 2^n-1\}$.

So now we show that $X_n$ is uniformly distributed on $A_n$. It is clear [due to the fact that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$] that, for **each integer** $n$ [no need to take limits], and each $k \in A_n = \{0 \le k < 2^n\}$, the following equation holds:

$$\mathbb{P}[X_n = k] = \mathbb{P}\Big[X \in \Big[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}\Big)\Big]$$
$$= \frac{(k+1)-k}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2^n},$$
where the "$=$" on the second line follows from the fact that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Then this gives $X_n$ uniformly distributed on $A_n$; indeed, for all $k \in A_n$, the probability that $X_n$ is $k$ is the same, namely $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: Do we know that $X_n$ only takes values $k\in A_n$?

Comment: That is straightforward. It is straightforward to see that $X_n = 2^n \frac{\lfloor X \rfloor}{2^n}$ must be an *integer* as the numerator and denominator are both integral and the numerator is a multiple of the denominator.  So if $X_n$ took a value $k$ not in $A_n$, then as $A_n$ is the set of nonnegative integers up to $2^n-1$, it follows that $k \ge 2^n$ or $k<0$. The former would imply $X>1$, the latter $X<0$....

Comment: Sorry could you maybe explain the second equality with the probability I don't see this one.

Comment: If $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, then for each $a,b \in [0,1]$ with $a<b$, the following equation holds: $\mathbb{P}[X \in [a,b)] = b-a$.

Comment: ah sorry I meant the first equality, the second one was clear

Comment: $\mathbb{P}[X_n=k] = \mathbb{P}[2^n \times \frac{\lfloor 2^nX \rfloor}{2^n} = k]$, which you should be able to check yourself that the equation  $2^n \times \frac{\lfloor 2^nX \rfloor}{2^n} = k$ is true, if and only if $X$ is between $k/2^n$ and $(k+1)/2^n$.

Comment: But $2^n\cdot \frac{\lfloor 2^n X\rfloor}{2^n}=\lfloor 2^n X\rfloor\neq X_n$? So you don't take my $X_n$

Comment: because with my $X_n$ it will not give $k$ if $X$ is in your given interval. Shouldn't then $X\in \left[\frac{k}{2^{2n}}, \frac{k+1}{2^{2n}}\right)$

Comment: No. With $X_n$ as you defined it, $X_n = \frac{k}{2^n}$ iff $X$ is in $[k/2^n, (k+1)/2^n)$. Note that $X_n$ as you defined it, satisfying $X_n=\frac{k}{2^n}$ is equivalent to $X_n$ as I defined it, satisfying $X_n=2^n \times \frac{k}{2^n} = k$.

Comment: But then I should compute $\Bbb{P}(X_n=\frac{k}{2^n})=...=\frac{1}{2^n}$ right?

Comment: I explained this pretty thoroughly already. At this point you should be able to go through the above and see all this for yourself.

Comment: YES @cristallo, with $X_n$ as you defined it, $\mathbb{P}[X_n = k/2^n]$ is $2^{-n}$, for **all** $k\in A_n$. With $X_n$ as I defined it, $\mathbb{P}[X_n =k]$ is  the same $2^{-n}$ as well, again, **for all** $k \in A_n$. This implies the uniform distribution on $A_n$ as desired.